# Looking for hibernate alternatives to @Embeddable @MappedSuperClass

Tags: hibernate

I am looking for alternatives to the following because the combination @Embeddable and @MappedSuperClass is not supported.

I have an Order entity that contains a Fulfillment Object. I want most of fulfillment fields on the Order table in the DB. This should be a classic case of using @Embedded and @Embeddable, but there are a couple of cases where I need extra information from another table(Vehicle) and I only want to get the extra data if the Fulfillment Type is Pickup.

The Fulfillment object is an abstract class where the concrete class is based on the Fulfillment type(Pickup, Delivery, ...)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="order")
public class Order {
  @Id
  @Column(name="order_id")
  private String id;

  @Embedded
  private Fulfillment fulfillment;
}

@Embeddable
@MappedSuperClass
public abstract class Fulfillment {

  @Column(name="fulfillment_type")
  private FulfillmentType type;
}

public class Pickup extends Fulfillment {
  private Vehicle vehicle;
}

public class Delivery extends Fulfillment {

}

@Entity
@Table(name="vehicle")
public class Vehicle {
  @Column(name="vehicle_id")
  private String id;

  @Column(name="make") 
  private String make;

  @Column(name="color")
  private String color;
}
```

I expect the 2 tables to be:

```
   order
   [
      order_id varchar,
      fulfillment_type varchar,
    ] 

    vehicle [
      vehicle_id varchar,
      make varchar,
      color varchar
    ]
```

Comment: It's right that you thought about the table model, because that leads to the question: Where is the `vehicle_id` of `Pickup` stored? And are there any other properties in `Delivery` or is it just a marker? I'm wondering, why you can't just store an optional vehicle in `Order` and make its usage depend on the fulfillment_type?

Comment: I left out a bunch of classes and properties on classes for brevity of the code. The vehicle object has many fields that would all be null for all but the Pickup type, in this example. 

The vehicle_id could be on the order table or the order_id could be on the vehicle table, depending on possible implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I would add *all* possible embeddables to your container class:

```
@Entity
public class Order {
  @Id
  private String id;

  private FulfillmentType type;

  @Embedded
  private Pickup pickup;

  @Embedded
  private Delivery delivery;

  public Fulfillment getFulfillment() {
    switch (type) {
      case PICKUP: return pickup;
      case DELIVERY: return delivery;
    }
  }
}

public abstract class Fulfillment {

}

@Embeddable
public class Pickup extends Fulfillment {
  @ManyToOne
  private Vehicle vehicle;
}

@Embeddable
public class Delivery extends Fulfillment {
  // ... attributes
}
```

The database layout would look like expected, with all the columns from `Pickup` and `Delivery` in the Order table. The biggest disadvantage is, that you can't define any column from `Pickup` or `Delivery` as `NotNull`, because that column would be `null` if the FulfillmentType is not of that type.

You could go with with an `Any` mapping as well, but as far as I can tell from your model and your description, the embeddables seem to be the best solution.